# Exporting Org to PDF while displaying Regex literal strings

Tags: org-export, latex, pdf

I've been searching for the past couple of days to a solution to an issue I'm having. Hoping somebody who is more apt with emacs/exporting could provide some insight.

Upon exporting an .org file (<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>o/p</kbd>) to LaTeX followed by PDF, my Regex text within the PDF document is handled (assuming) as a math equation. E.g. instead of displaying [^ABC] within the PDF, it is displayed as [<sup>ABC</sup>].

I have attempted to use \usepackage{verbatim}, with something like \verb/[^ABC]/, but I get different results. E.g. [(^{\text{ABC}})].

Is there a specific reason I'm missing that could be causing this? Or, something that I have not included within my init.el? For reference, here is the section of my init.el that is handling org-latex-classes:

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
             '("adarticle"
               "\\documentclass{article}
\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\\usepackage{verbatim}
\\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\\usepackage{graphicx}
\\usepackage{longtable}
\\usepackage{hyperref}
\\usepackage{natbib}
\\usepackage{amssymb}
\\usepackage{amsmath}
\\usepackage{geometry}
\\geometry{a4paper,left=2.5cm,top=2cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,marginparsep=7pt, marginparwidth=.6in}"
               ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
               ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
               ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
               ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
               ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

Edit: As suggested, wrapping expressions with '=' seems to do the trick for cases such as [^ABC] and \u{FFFF}.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the offending text in '=' markup? Seems to do the right thing here at least for '^'

Comment: @rpluim No clue how I didn't find any information on this - I did try it with a couple of expressions and it seems to do the trick! Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Using #+BEGIN_EXAMPLE / #+END_EXAMPLE blocks works as well for bigger chunks

Comment: This is great information, and both seem to be suitable use cases for what I'm going for. Thanks again! If you'd like to answer directly so I can mark as complete, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Org can be told to treat text as verbatim either by wrapping it in '=' markup (for words), or in a `#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE`/`#+END_EXAMPLE` block. See [Emphasis-and-Monospace](https://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-Monospace.html) and [Literal-Examples](https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html) for details.